# vba filter only on character value

Tags: excel, filtering, vba

I want to make a filter to see rows that contain any character.

For example, column A contains 124124, 4231, R2341, RRR

Then I would like to see R2341, RRR from column A. Is there any way to filter only on character string?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Text Filter *Contains* feature in AutoFilter:

[image]

Or with VBA:

```
Sub Macro1()
    Columns("A:A").AutoFilter
    ActiveSheet.Range("$A$1:$A$5").AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="=*R*", _
        Operator:=xlAnd
End Sub
```

**EDIT#1:**

To test for the presence of ANY letter, use this *UDF()* in a helper column:

```
Public Function HasLetter(v As Variant) As Boolean
    Dim i As Long, L As Long
    HasLetter = False
    If Len(v) = 0 Then Exit Function
    L = Len(v)
    For i = 1 To L
        If Mid(v, i, 1) Like "[a-zA-Z]" Then
            HasLetter = True
            Exit Function
        End If
    Next i
End Function
```

and filter on *True*.

Comment: that was just an example. I need to get any values that contain any character. Is there any way to make a filter like this?

Comment: @terny  See my **EDIT#1**